# Background color stays transparent, though devtools says it's white

Tags: html, css, background-color, drupal-8

Background color of the first paragraph on the main-content of [my Drupal website](https://openvillage.ch) stays transparent, though it is defined as white in the CSS, and even Devtools says it's white... it sounds noobish and so simple, yet I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

HTML:

```html
<div class="clearfix main-content region--dark-typography region--white-background  region--no-separator">
    <div class="container">...</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.region--white-background {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it at random!

It was a bug created by Drupal's appear on scroll animations. Javascript was disabling my background color after CSS created it. I had to to to appearance -> setings -> animations -> select "none" for the region called "main-content"

Answer (score -1):

put the div with "region region-content" class white background and it works!

Answer (score -1):

```css
 .region--white-background {
            background-color: #ffffff;
        }
```

```html
<div class=" region--white-background ">
        <div class="container" style="color:black;">If you want to set background color to white then you'll have to set the color of the content to other than white.I have set it to black using in-line css.
Hope you'll be satisfied.
</div>
    </div>
```